# How to use Join() Expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, inner-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a join in linq to sql with method syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax)

How do I use join() expression?

[image: Here, my model edmx]

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches the specified term.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="term">The term.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<City> Search(string term, string countryAbbrev, string provinceAbbrev)
    {
        //if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(province))
        return context.Cities.join(????).Where(Cty => Cty.Name.Contains(term)).ToList();
    }
```

I would like to join with `Province` and `country`. I know How to do with "`From .. in .. join..`" but not with this Expression `Join(???)`

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! That's my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to do the join as the entities are already in relationship so you can use the **navigation properties** to get a list of related records

For example to get all the cities for a province you can do the below:

```
var citiesInProvince=context.Province.Single(x => x.id==*AnyID*)
                             .Cities;
```

Comment: yes, but i receive `ProvinceAbbrev` and `CountryAbbrev` and i want to research City with these clauses