# Is there some sort of syntax error with this LINQ JOIN?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I've looked at [various questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax) on SO and [other sites](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join), and this *appears* to be the correct syntax to perform a `JOIN` in LINQ, however it's just not working:

```
var stages = (from stage in entityManager.TPM_TASKSTAGE select stage);
var results = (from task in pv.TPM_TASK
               join st in stages on st.STAGEID equals task.STAGEID
               where task.TASKTYPE == "Solution"
               select new SolutionTask());
```

Ignore, for now, the fact that I don't actually *select* anything of interest, but I'd like to have access to the `st.NAME` property on each row of `TPM_TASK`.  The two tables are linked by `STAGEID`.  I get the compiler error:

> The name 'st' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider
>   swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

In the LINQ join expression, both `st` and `task` have red squigglies.  Please tell me I'm doing something dumb.

Comment: Did you try following the exact instructions in the error message? ("Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'")

Comment: @JonSkeet - That was actually the *first* thing I tried, however my expression was `task.STAGEID == st.STAGEID`.  This yields a similar compiler error (suggesting I swap the expressions).  So I did, and also switched to `equals` thinking that might make a difference.  I did not try `task.STAGEID equals st.STAGEID` which is the valid combination!  Sigh.

Comment: When you had `task.STAGEID == st.STAGEID` you wouldn't have got the same error message, because your join would have been *completely* invalid at that point.

Comment: @JonSkeet - You are right about that, however Visual Studio seems to *cache* that error message temporarily until you do a full compile.  It seems the IDE's error checking doesn't catch the `==` on the fly, but does catch the fact that it cannot resolve the context of `st`.  My fault for not doing a compile to see the *real* error messages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Key selector from outer sequence should go first. Outer sequence in your case is `pv.TPM_TASK`. So, you should join on `task.STAGEID equals st.STAGEID`

```
var stages = (from stage in entityManager.TPM_TASKSTAGE select stage);
var results = (from task in pv.TPM_TASK
               join st in stages on task.STAGEID equals st.STAGEID // here
               where task.TASKTYPE == "Solution"
               select new SolutionTask());
```

Comment: Picky compiler.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @MikeChristensen: It's really not a matter of being picky. The two sides of `equals` have completely different scopes: the left side has no knowledge of `st`, and the right side has no knowledge of `task`. For this sort of thing, it's useful to think about what the query expression syntax really means. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx for more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the info!  I'm kinda a LINQ novice, and get thrown off easily when it comes to the more complicated things like joins.  I figured they worked similar to a SQL JOIN, where the order of operands doesn't matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet's link is broken. Use this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/