# Merging DataTables with Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, datatable, merge

I would like to merge `DataTable`s in a list using sum or average depending on conditions. For example:

```
private DataTable getData(List<DataTable> datas, string[] KeyColumnNames, string valueCol)
{
    List<DataTable> dataTables = datas;
    //if datas has 3 dataTables in it : dt1, dt2, dt3
    // then I want to create another dataTable dtAll which will have the sum of 
    // valueCol of all three datatables for the row which  will be conditioned using 
    // KeyColumnNames (can be multiple Primary keys)
    return dataTable;
}
```

Consider all datatables to be exactly same but different values as they are tables from similar schemas but different data centers.
Thanks.

Comment: Consider using LINQ it has ability to aggregate as well as union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
List<DataTable> dataTableList = dtList;
DataTable unionDataTable = new DataTable();
for(int i = 0; i < dtList.Count; i++)
    unionDataTable = Union(unionDataTable, dtList[i], "UnionDataTable");
```

where the `Union` method is defined by something like the following

```
public static DataTable Union(DataTable First, DataTable Second, string strReturnedTableName)
{
    // Result table.
    DataTable table = new DataTable(strReturnedTableName);

    // Build new columns.
    DataColumn[] newcolumns = new DataColumn[First.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < First.Columns.Count; i++)
        newcolumns[i] = new DataColumn(First.Columns[i].ColumnName, First.Columns[i].DataType);

    // Add new columns to result table.
    table.Columns.AddRange(newcolumns);
    table.BeginLoadData();

    // Load data from first table.
    foreach (DataRow row in First.Rows)
        table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, true);

    // Load data from second table.
    foreach (DataRow row in Second.Rows)
        table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, true);

    table.EndLoadData();
    return table;
}
```

I hope this helps.

*Edit. You can pass an `Action` in to the method and use this in the `foreach` blocks to do what you want.*

Comment: this will just merge the data, I need to perform operations on data. Something like column value of unionDataTable will have sum or average of values from all the tables.

Comment: See edit. I can't write the entire code for you but the above should be a good start...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too vague to provide any actual code but you want to do a LINQ `Join`. It works about the same as a SQL join. This question shows joins in both query and method syntax [How to do a join in linq to sql with method syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax) also you can look at the msdn docs here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx