# Creating a single Type from muliple entities in Lambda

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, lambda

I have 3 entities

[image: My Entities]
I'd like to flatten the *tblCondition* and *BusinessAreas* into one object.   What I want is `Category.ID, Category.Category, BusinessArea.ID, BusinessArea AreaName`.

I know this can be done by creating an Anonymous type with Lambda but I'm relatively unskilled with Lampda or LINQ.

Forgot to mention that I need to get to the two tables through the first one.

My original call looks like this.

```
myConditionTemplate = EE.ConditionTemplates.Where(c => c.TemplateCode == TextBoxSearchConditionCode.Text).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384105.aspx

Essentially in your select portion use the new keyword without a class name like:

```
select new { Category.ID, Category.Category, BusinessArea.ID, BusinessArea.AreaName }
```

The webpage only shows an example using Linq in query form, but to do it in method form:

```
var results = db.GetStuff().Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Name });
```

Ack, that may not be very clear.  I just found some great examples at [How to do a join in linq to sql with method syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax).  This was a different question, but the answer's example shows you how to do the lamba for a joined enumerable set.

**UPDATE:** Since you updated your question, see if this helps:

```
var results = myConditionTemplate.Select(x => new { CategoryID = x.tblCondition.ID, Category = x.tblCondition.Category, BusinessAreaID = x.tblCondition.BusinessArea.ID, AreaName = x.tblCondition.BusinessArea.AreaName});
```

Comment: By the way, I learned a TON from Tekpub.com's tutorial series on Mastering Linq.  Shamelessly I'll post my referral code: http://tekpub.refr.cc/F7B888K.  :)  But either way, check them out.  Tons of great stuff.