# How to load Data from a second table in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linq-to-sql

i have to tables: Users and PrivateMessages.
Users has UserID and Username.
PrivateMessages has the coloumns PMID and Text and SenderID.
(of course it has much more but to explain the problem, its enough)

Now I have a DataSource and a method like this:

```
    public static List<UserPM> GetAllPMsAsSender(Guid userID)
    {
        using (RPGDataContext dc = new RPGDataContext())
        {
            return (from a in dc.UserPMs where a.Sender == userID && !a.IsDeletedSender orderby a.Timestamp select a).ToList();
        }
    }
```

and bind it to the ObjectDataSource with is bound to the Grid View.

The Grid view now looks like these:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsOutcome" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetAllPMsAsSender" TypeName="DAL.PMDAL">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="UserID" DbType="Guid" Name="userID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="gridOut" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="odsOutcome">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMID" HeaderText="PMID" SortExpression="PMID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text" SortExpression="Text"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So how I can get the Username in this field instead the UserID?

Answer (score 1):

Try using join and select the user name too for your object data source and use the user name to display it instead of user id.
Refer this link [How to do a join in linq to sql with method syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax)