# Joining Tables Using Entity Framerwork Fluent Syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I have tables Table1, Table2, Table3 and so on. To handle auditing, I use Audit table with the following fields Id, Username, ChangeTime, ChangeType, TableName and TableRecordId.

To obtain all records in Table1 joined with Audit on Table1.Id = Audit.TableRecordId where Username is "jdoe" for example, I have the following:

```
var results = db.Table1s
            .Join(db.Audits.Where(a => a.Username == "jdoe"),
            t => t.Id,
            a => a.RecordId,
            (t, a) => new { Table1 = t, Audit = a });
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SampleApp.Models.Table1,AuditLibraryContext.Models.Audit]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AuditTrackerSample.Models.Table1]'.
```

Got it working I ended up with the following code:

```
var results = db.Table1s
            .Join(db.Audits.Where(a => a.Username == "jdoe"),
            t => t.Id,
            a => a.RecordId,
            (t, a) => t);
```

Comment: What do your entities look like? Using navigation properties, you shouldn't have to join since EF does it for you.

Comment: Can't use navigation because I don't have direct access to the Audit class which is part of a third party library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do a thorough search before asking a general duplicate question.

```
var results = db.Table1s
              .Join(db.Audits.Where(a => a.Username == "jdoe"),
              t => t.Id,
              a => a.TableRecordId,
              (t, a) => new { Table1 = t, Audit = a });

var results = from t in db.Table1s
              join a in db.Audits
              on t.Id equals a.TableRecordId
              where a.Username == "jdoe"
              select new { Table1 = t, Audit = a};
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax)

Comment: Thanks. I did some research before asking and I did find some stuff but not exactly what I am looking for and I am having a hard time figuring out exactly how to apply them in my situation.

Comment: Oh and Username is part of the Audit table not Table1.

Comment: Where clause has been fixed, as per your clarification.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Please close-vote a question as duplicate when finding a duplicate.

Comment: It does not appear that anyone, other than yourself, that have responded, have sufficient reputation to cast a close vote. :(

Comment: I tried the above fluid syntax but I am getting the following error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[AuditSample.Models.Table1,AuditLibraryContext.Models.Audit]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AuditSample.Models.Table1]'.