# Select from multiple list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have multiple list of class.

```
public class MainClass
{
 public List<A> a{ get; set; }
 public List<B> b{ get; set; }
 public List<C> c{ get; set; }
}
```

**And main class contains following property**

```
 class A
    {
      public string Name{ get; set; }
      public string MainAddress{get;set;}
    }

    class B
    {
      public int ID {get;set;}
      public string Address{ get; set; }
    }

    class C
    {
     public int ID {get;set;}
      public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

Now how do i fetch **data from List b & c** and pass it to **A** This is what i tried

```
  List<A> query = (from b in MainClass.b
               join c in Mainclass.c
                on b.ID equals c.ID
                select new {b.Address, c.Name});
```

**How do i display Name from C as MainAddress in A**

Comment: What you need is a JOIN operation between them, based on their ID property they both have. The answer to this question gives you that: [How to do a join in linq to sql with method syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217669/how-to-do-a-join-in-linq-to-sql-with-method-syntax)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I am not asking how to join, i am just asking how do i display from one list to another

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `select new {b.B, c.C}` does not compile since `B` and `C` don't have properties `B` and `C`. Do you want to initialize `MainClass.a` with all linked `Name+Address` properties of the other collections? If so, how do you want to build the `MainAddress`?

Comment: `on a.ID equals b.ID` is invalid as `a` has not been defined anywhere.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That was a typo.Edited

Comment: @AndyNichols That was a typo.Edited

Comment: @Richa: it's still not clear, how do you want to construct `MainAddress`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter MainAddress should contain data fetched from Address in B

Comment: @Richa: and the `Name` from `C`?

Comment: I have added the lambda example check it out in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a complete Snippet of the demo code: http://share.linqpad.net/aq8f6c.linq

To get the address from B displayed as the Mainadress in A do the following:

```
var result = from a in As
             join b in (from b in Bs
                        join c in Cs
                        on b.ID equals c.ID
                        select new {b.Address, c.Name})
             on a.Name equals b.Name
             select new A {
                 Name = a.Name,
                 MainAddress = b.Address
             };
```

`result` then is of type `Ienumerable<A>`.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that what you want is a List of A having  MainAddresses comming from the c list.
If so:

```
 var query = (from b in MainClass.b
               join c in Mainclass.c
                on b.ID equals c.ID
                select new A { MainAddress = c.Name });
```

**Edit**:
I went ahead and made a full working example so that you can check your mistakes...

- A, B, and C classes must have the same visibility as a, b, and c properties.
- You are accessing b and c statically but they are instance variables.

Of course the transformation from Enumerable to List can be made in one step by calling the ToList selector directly on the Enumerable instance.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mainClass = new MainClass();

            mainClass.b = new List<B>();
            mainClass.c = new List<C>();
            mainClass.b.Add(new B { ID = 1, Address = "B1" });
            mainClass.c.Add(new C { ID = 1, Name = "C1" });

            //using LINQ
            var query = (from b in mainClass.b
                         join c in mainClass.c
                          on b.ID equals c.ID
                         select new A { MainAddress = c.Name });

            List<A> fromLINQ = query.ToList();

            //using anonymous functions aka lambda expressions
            IEnumerable<A> enumerableFromAnonymous = mainClass.b.Join(mainClass.c, x => x.ID, x => x.ID, (x, y) => { return new A() { MainAddress = y.Name }; });
            List<A> listFromAnonymous = enumerableFromAnonymous.ToList();
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public List<A> a { get; set; }
        public List<B> b { get; set; }
        public List<C> c { get; set; }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MainAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants `mainClass.a = query.ToList();`.

Comment: @Sam can you check mdified query above

Comment: The query seems fine. A must be visible in the code where you are using the statement. It returns an IEnumerable of A and as Tim commented above it can be enumerated to a List of A with query.ToList().

Comment: @Jaycee who said ToList can be called twice? In fact nowhere in my code ToList is called more than once on the same Enumerable...

Answer (score 0):

I thought Serv's example was the correct answer but I did not like the query syntax as I find this more difficult to read and maintain due to Visual Studio's inability to support Lambda expressions in the immediate window - as of VS2013.

I prefer method syntax using an intermediate variable. This saves screen space and I think it is easier to understand:

```
   var query = from a in As
                join c in (from b in Bs
                           join c in Cs
                           on b.ID equals c.ID
                           select new {b.Address, c.Name})
                on a.Name equals c.Name
                select new A {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    MainAddress = c.Address
                };
    query.Dump();

    //method sytnax
    var nameAddress = Bs.Join(Cs, b => b.ID, c => c.ID, (b, c) => new { Name = c.Name, Address = b.Address });
    var query2 = As.Join(nameAddress, a => a.Name, na => na.Name, (a, na) => new { Name = a.Name, MainAddress = na.Address});
    query2.Dump();
```